# How to unwind an array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Could you please confirm how to unwind the following array of two elements?

```
null, 20320
photo, 809
photo,photo, 2
```

Please find one of the documents in JSON [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hGy4I69R6jrr3G59w1_kQyaMx1kkVF0Jb_8bXuE8ttA/edit).

I tried the following code but it's not affecting any records:

```
db.tweets.aggregate([{$unwind : "$entities.media.type"}])
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text instead for your documents.

Comment: Sure. How can I do that Wernfried?

Comment: In the same way as you did for `db.tweets.aggregate([{$unwind : "$entities.media.type"}])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In unwind stage ,there should be an array field

so the query will look like following,you can unwind till `media` as its an array

```
db.tweets.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$entities.media"
  }
])
```

Now if you want to group by

```
db.tweets.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$entities.media"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$entities.media.type",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YveeLiY7ltt)